# Ruby on Rails four-way association tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, model-associations

The big picture: I am creating an app to track temporal events historically. I am setting it up with four main models: Users, Events, Stories and Images. The idea is that any given user can create an Event, and add Stories and/or Images to his own Event or to any other one. But both Stories and Images are always attached to a certain Event, and any other model belongs to the User who created it (for filtering and editing purposes)

The general structure of the associations would be something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :stories
  has_many :images
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stories
  has_many :images
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I am kind of new to Rails and I have little-to-no control over more complex associations as many_to_many, through: or as:

My question here is, is this set of associations optimal, or could it be improved by combining them in a different way?

Comment: I suggest reading up on **[Polymorphic Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations)**.

Comment: Polymorphic associations would only apply to this if story and image had to belong to event **and** user at the same time, which is not the case.

Comment: Story and Image actually have to belong to a certain Event and an User at the same time always. The only thing is that a Story may belong to a different User from the one who created the Event it is attached to

Answer (score 2):

You're in the right track, but `story` and `image` shouldn't belong to `user`. You're creating a redundancy in there.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :stories, :through => :events
  has_many :images, :through => :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stories
  has_many :images
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

This way you can still write `user.stories` and `user.images`.

Comment: I see, very interesting. But final question: does the :through setup above imply that only the user who created the Event can own the Stories and Images contained? Because it will be the case where User A created the event, but User B added a Story to it and User C attached two image to this same Event, each entwined model then belonging to different Users...

Comment: I think you're confusing authorization with the data model. Being able to update attributes has nothing to do with model relationships. You could conceivably have a different user add images to an instance of `Event`, but as long as they belong to the same event, `story.event.user` will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot @depa, will give it a try see how this works! I guess story.event.user will be different than story.user then?

Comment: Now, if you actually **wanted** stories and images to belong to **different** users from the event owner, then we would be talking about something else.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, but that is exactly what I mean. ;)

Comment: Haha, OK. Then your initial associations will work just fine. Maybe just use `belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'` in `Event` so you don't confuse it with the other kind of ownership.

Comment: That sounds great, thanks a lot @depa. Will give it a try and accept if working!

Comment: Cool, but foreign_key should be added to the association: `belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use nested attributes:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Sample code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stories
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stories, :images
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Nested attributes accepts many level. In this case, there are 3 levels

1. user
2. event
3. story and image.

It like the sample at [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) with 3 level (survey - question -answer).

Look at the link above and watch the [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) to see how it work.

Or you can't look at my sample, but it work with 2 levels(subject - task).

Link at [here](http://framgia-tms.herokuapp.com/supervisor/subjects/new)

Login with account: duyet.vn@gmail.com/12341234