# Current_event adding a song(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have developed an app where a user can log in and view their events. The event can be clicked on and in that events show page you can add songs. The problem I am having is that when you click submit after filling out the song field it gives me an error because it can't find the event id that the songs are adding to. How would I define a current_event method to retrieve the clicked on event from the user? This is what I have so far in my songs controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @song = current_event.songs.build(songs_params)
        if @song.save
            flash[:success] = "Song created"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "Failed"
        end

    end

    def destroy
    end
    private

      def micropost_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:artist, :title, :genre)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define nested routes.

Maybe, on routes.rb:

```
resources :events do
  resources :songs
end
```

And now, the path to new song like `localhost:3000/events/1/songs/new`

You have `params[:event_id] = 1`

And on your controller, action create, you can call

```
current_event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
```

Comment: I will be sure to try this out and let you know my results

Comment: Defining the route events/1/songs/new would take me to the songs new page. But I want the songs to be displayed and entered in all on the events page. And for defining current_event, would I just need to define that variable in the create action of my SongsController

Comment: Did u want to do somethings like [this](http://framgia-tms.herokuapp.com/supervisor/subjects/new). Login with `duyet.vn@gmail.com/12341234`

Comment: YES! This is almost exactly how I want my app to be formatted. Instead, users have events and those events can have songs.

Comment: I did answer the same problem at [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648245/ruby-on-rails-four-way-association-tree/40881316#40881316). The best tutorial at rails cast, [part1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [part2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Comment: I will be sure to look at these tutorials, thank you very much!

Comment: Btw, maybe you need to view my code at above example. You cant fork at [github](https://github.com/framgia/tms_33/tree/develop)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131015/discussion-between-aaron-and-duyet-nguyen).